# Searching link list recursiverly in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I am new to data structures. I have written a fairly simple program to search for an integer in a link list. Function is suppose to return pointer to relevant position, but when called in main() it is returning null(or just garbage may be). (printf messages are inserted for diagnostics.)

Link list :

```
struct list
{
        int data;
        struct list * link;
};
```

Search function :

```
struct list * search_list(struct list * head_ptr, int x)
{
        printf("\nfunc search head addr : 0X%x ",head_ptr);
        if(head_ptr==NULL)
        {
                printf("Null found.\n");
                return NULL;
        }

        else if (head_ptr->data == x)
        {
                printf("element found returing : 0X%x ",head_ptr);
                return head_ptr;
        }
        else
        {
                printf("not found , next");
                search_list(head_ptr->link,x);
        }

}
```

Call inside main () :

```
tmp_list_ptr = list_head_ptr;
tmp_list_ptr = search_list(list_head_ptr,15);
if(tmp_list_ptr == NULL)
        printf("main : Not found : 0X%x\n",tmp_list_ptr);
else
        printf("main : found at : 0X%x\n",tmp_list_ptr);
```

return 0;

Program Output :

```
[0X1dd33250 : 19,]
[0X1dd33230 : 18,]
[0X1dd33210 : 17,]
[0X1dd331f0 : 16,]
[0X1dd331d0 : 15,]
[0X1dd331b0 : 14,]
[0X1dd33190 : 13,]
[0X1dd33170 : 12,]
[0X1dd33150 : 11,]
[0X1dd33130 : 1,]
[0X1dd33110 : 2,]
[0X1dd330f0 : 3,]
[0X1dd330d0 : 4,]
[0X1dd330b0 : 5,]
[0X1dd33090 : 6,]
[0X1dd33070 : 7,]
[0X1dd33050 : 8,]
[0X1dd33030 : 9,]
[0X1dd33010 : 10,]
Searching for 15. 
func search head addr : 0X1dd33250 not found , next
func search head addr : 0X1dd33230 not found , next
func search head addr : 0X1dd33210 not found , next
func search head addr : 0X1dd331f0 not found , next
func search head addr : 0X1dd331d0 element found returing : 0X1dd331d0 main : Not found : 0X0
```

Why it is returning NULL to main ?
Could you help me please?
Note : Example taken from : The Algorithm Design Manual, Steven S. Skiena, 2nd edition
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhEZC.png

Comment: should be `return search_list(head_ptr->link,x);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : That's **the answer**. You wrote it at wrong place... :-)

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild, it will short answer. It is not a detailed answer. Thank you on my behalf. answer is his link.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : You can add details. You can explain the problem to OP if you want. :-)

Comment: I think he should look at the page again. :)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : Yup! Right!!

Comment: Oh my. May God forgive my blunders. Thank you for your responses. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive call of `search_list()` should actually `return` the result. Instead, your function is calling `search_list()` recursively and then implicitly throwing away its return value.

This should have generated a compiler warning, such as "control reaches end of non-void function."

Depending on your computer's architecture, you may end up with garbage results. This is what we refer to as "undefined behavior"! For example, on a 32-bit Intel processor, the return value of a function is stored in the `eax` register. Depending on how the compiler decided your program would use the processor's registers, your function may have returned the result of some other computation.